# What is the best solution to merge one column by another column in MariaDB?

Tags: sql, performance, mariadb, concatenation

I have a table like this :

```
c1 | c2 
===+===
1  | 0
---+---
3  | 5
---+---
2  | 1 
---+---
3  | 2 
---+---
4  | 2 
---+---
4  | 3
---+---
7  | 3
```

and I want to convert it to :

```
c1      | c2 
========+==========
1       | 0
--------+----------
2       | 1 
--------+----------
3,4,7   | 5+2+2+3+3
```

When I use PHP recursive function, the performance is not good enough in more than 200 milion records.

Comment: With 200 records you do not have to worry about performance. What's the logic behind the groupings?

Comment: @Shadow its 200 million

Comment: I guess you don't want to perform a random concat. Can you share the rules (they are not so obvious to me) ? and for the result you want the string "5+2+2+3+3" or "15" ?

Comment: @Tuckbros these numbers are my key ids which are defined in another table. In second related table we define process time, task name & operator number for each key. for exp. (5 means =>>> task: x , process time:20sec , operator no: 26)

Comment: @RakeshNair the million was added after I made the comment.

Comment: @RakeshNair excuse me, it was missed.

Comment: @mahtab . . . Are you planning on having a string with a summary of millions of values as a string?

Comment: Why weren't 0 and 1 'converted'?  (I don't see the pattern.)